# Get percentage from row values

Tags: php, sql

I am using PHP with ORACLE.

`SELECT AIP.TERMID, (select count(RAU.TERMNAME) FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU WHERE RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 21) as page_views
, COUNT(case when aip.ctype = 'download' then 1 else null end) as page_download
, COUNT(case when aip.ctype = 'event' then 1 else null end) as page_event
 FROM REPORT_API_PAGES AIP 
 GROUP BY AIP.TERMID`

This is my query to get details. I need to find the percentage of `page_views`, `page_download`, & `page_event`

Comment: There is no such thing as `foreach` loop in SQL. And the code you have show is not SQL either. What programming language is that? And where does a relational database come into play?

Comment: what's result you want to get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91234/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT_API_USAGE
    ("VOCID" int, "TERMNAME" varchar2(9))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (21, 'blah blah')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      TERMNAME
    , COUNT(TERMNAME) as count_of
    , (COUNT(TERMNAME) * 100.0) / MAX(TOTCOUNT) as pct
FROM (
    SELECT
          AP.TERMNAME
        , COUNT(AP.TERMNAME) OVER() as TOTCOUNT
    FROM REPORT_API_USAGE AP
    WHERE AP.VOCID = '21'
  ) 
GROUP BY TERMNAME
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91234/4/0)**:

```
|  TERMNAME | COUNT_OF |               PCT |
|-----------|----------|-------------------|
|      blah |        5 | 38.46153846153846 |
| blah blah |        8 | 61.53846153846154 |
```

longer string version:

```
SELECT TERMNAME , COUNT(TERMNAME) as count_of , (COUNT(TERMNAME) * 100.0) / MAX(TOTCOUNT) as pct FROM ( SELECT AP.TERMNAME , COUNT(AP.TERMNAME) OVER() as TOTCOUNT FROM REPORT_API_USAGE AP WHERE AP.VOCID = '21' ) GROUP BY TERMNAME
```

Comment: Can i get it using PHP code instead of SQL. I am already have a long SQL.

Comment: Not from me, I don't code in PHP. It's just a longer query string (and not even that much longer) simply remove the line breaks.

Comment: No  Used_By_Already. I already have a long SQL. I just posted one portion in my question. If i add you SQL , it will longer and complex.

Comment: V.Sorry, you asked a question, I answered it. + How would I know what the remainder of your existing query is? ++ I really don't do PHP. Look at the sql I used, it only adds a bit more to the query you supplied in the question.

Comment: How sad (the overall query was not shown in the original question). That overall query structure does not allow my suggestion to be used. A "correlated subquery" used inside a select clause can only return a single value.

Comment: Used_By_Already, thanks for your suggestion. Can you tell me how can i find the total sum of  `page_views` column. I will get percentage using php coding. `SELECT AIP.TERMID,
(select count(RAU.TERMNAME) FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU WHERE RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4) as page_views
from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
GROUP BY AIP.TERMID`

Comment: please look at new solution approach

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your last comment

Comment: Can you update your answer according to my latest question.

Comment: have you not read my other answer? it does exactly what you have now asked for... I think

Answer (score 0):

Generating sample data to work with is something the asker should provide because we have to largely guess what goes in the tables. With many reservations I created a sample and trialed the following approach.

Note I am offering the SQL portion only, manipulating this into suitable PHP you must do.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43e4e/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT_API_USAGE
    (TERMID int, VOCID int, TERMNAME varchar2(1))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
    INTO REPORT_API_USAGE ("TERMID", "VOCID", "TERMNAME")
         VALUES (1, 21, 'x')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE REPORT_API_PAGES
    (TERMID int, CTYPE varchar2(8))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'download')
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'event')
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'download')
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'event')
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'download')
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'event')
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'download')
    INTO REPORT_API_PAGES ("TERMID", "CTYPE")
         VALUES (1, 'event')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      AIP.TERMID
    , RAU.page_views
    , COUNT(CASE
            WHEN aip.ctype = 'download' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
      END) AS page_download
    , COUNT(CASE
            WHEN aip.ctype = 'event' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
      END) AS page_event
    , (COUNT(CASE
            WHEN aip.ctype = 'download' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
      END) * 100.0) / RAU.page_views as dnload_pt
    , (COUNT(CASE
            WHEN aip.ctype = 'event' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
      END) * 100.0) / RAU.page_views as event_pct

FROM REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            TERMID
          , COUNT(*) AS page_views
      FROM REPORT_API_USAGE
      WHERE VOCID = 21
      GROUP BY TERMID
          ) RAU ON RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID
GROUP BY
      AIP.TERMID
    , RAU.page_views
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43e4e/8/0)**:

```
| TERMID | PAGE_VIEWS | PAGE_DOWNLOAD | PAGE_EVENT |         DNLOAD_PT |         EVENT_PCT |
|--------|------------|---------------|------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      1 |          9 |             4 |          4 | 44.44444444444444 | 44.44444444444444 |
```